# Do functions vary depending on a secure SSL connection?

Tags: php, function, ssl

I have a script that loads pages from a "pages" folder. We have been loading this from the index.php file successfully and it has worked perfectly.

Now we have changed the connection from http to https we are getting a 500 error. Is it possible that https does not allow our script or is there something else at work?

This is the script loader located in the index.php file:

```
<?php
// 301 redirects
$redirectsTo = '';
$pathinfo = pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if(isset($pathinfo['extension']))
{
    if($pathinfo['dirname'] != '/')
        $redirectsTo = "{$pathinfo['dirname']}/{$pathinfo['filename']}";
    else
        $redirectsTo = "{$pathinfo['filename']}";
}

if($pathinfo['filename'] == 'index')
{
    $redirectsTo = "{$pathinfo['dirname']}/";
}

if(!empty($redirectsTo))
{
    $statusCode = 301;
    header("{$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']} $statusCode Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: $redirectsTo");
    exit;
}


// script loader 
if(!isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URI']))
{
    $load = 'pages/home.php';
}
else 
{
    $script = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URI'];
    $exploded = explode('/', $script);
    $script = end($exploded);
    $load = "pages/{$script}.php";
}


if(!file_exists($load))
{
    $load = '404.php';
}

require_once '_local.php';
include $load;
```

Comment: When you get a 500 error, check your PHP error log for the detailed reason.

Comment: 500 errors are very generic. What is the specific error in your logs?

Comment: `header("{$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']} $statusCode Moved Permanently");` this is wrong, not even sure what you want to do here

Comment: @smith That should just be `header("$statusCode Moved Permanently")`. He's trying to override the default 302 code that's used for redirects.

Comment: Yes exactly @Barmar, the error code is 500 - 613 The specified content type is not supported by this request.

Comment: This works correctly on the standard http connection, I'm wondering how does SSL cause this to function differently?

Comment: Are you redirecting POST requests? That won't work.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why changing to SSL would affect this.

Comment: Just want to load pages from a "pages" folder!

Comment: It should be simple enough, I'm wondering where I'm going wrong!

Comment: This sounds more like a server error than a PHP issue

Comment: I was thinking that @Barmar these 123 reg people installed the SSL certificate, I'm wondering if there is something we need to tweak to "allow" the script. Unfortunately I don't have root access to the server.

Comment: Can you access other pages on the server using SSL, without going through this redirect script?

Comment: @Barmar Yes the site we have is still there on http, I can even access the homepage fine through SSL which is located in the "pages" folder but when loading other files the dreaded 500 error comes up. So pages/home.php actually loads!

Comment: Then the certificate is probably OK. ServerFault.com might be a better place for your question, but you'll probably have to post details of the server configuration.